# Problema "The requested URL /wp-login.php was not found on this server." no wordpress, o que fazer?

Tags: php, wordpress

Olá,

Estou com um grande problema relacionado ao site do Laboratório cujo sou bolsista.

Meu professor orientador pediu que eu fizesse algumas alterações no site do Laboratório desenvolvido na plataforma WordPress. Ele pediu pra eu fazer uma coisa e acabei fazendo outra, por pura "curiosidade." Como não sou programador, fui "fuçando" o editor online do WordPress por uma idiotice resolvi apagar o /wordpress que tinha depois do link do site no editor: o site era "www.prologis.ufsc.br/wordpress" e eu alterei para "www.prologis.ufsc.br". 
Desde então o site ficou com o layout desconfigurado e não consigo mais acessar o editor online do WordPress pra reverter a alteração feita, pois sempre que vou logar aparece uma página com o erro:

> "The requested URL /wp-login.php was not found on this server. Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at www.prologis.ufsc.br Port 80"

Depois de ter pesquisado, entendi que eu deveria alterar isso diretamente no servidor. Acessei o servidor da Universidade via SFTP, e conforme recomendado por um artigo no fórum do WordPress para casos como o meu, adicionei as linhas:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://prologis.ufsc.br/wordpress');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://prologis.ufsc.br/wordpress'); // no arquivo wp-config.php.
```

Aí a situação piorou: antes, o site ficava com o layout desconfigurado. Depois dessa alteração, o site ficou todo branco.

Alguém sabe qual a alteração certa a se fazer e em qual arquivo pra reverter esse erro?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Se você alterou o o diretório dos arquivos para a raiz do site, você deveria adicionar as linhas da seguinte forma no `wp-config.php` (sem a pasta `WordPress` no final):

```
define('WP_HOME','http://prologis.ufsc.br/');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://prologis.ufsc.br/');
```